# Access vba : update forms

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am currently trying to create a logging tool for multiple Acces databases. 
Each Acces Database will look the same and will contain the same type of fields.

The goal: All records from Database A, B, C should be updatable in the same A, B, C database + upon creation sent to Database X.

When the record is edited in Database A, B or C, it should also be updated automatically in Database X.
When the record is edited in Database X it should also be updated automatically in Database A, B or C (depending on which database the record belongs to).

All help is welcome, 
thanks in advance.

Below, You can see the code I have so far.
Please also see following image of the setup I need:
[Insert/update between Acces Databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xORM.jpg)

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    'Click on button Add gives 2 options
    '1. insert
    '2. update

    '1. insert if new ID:
    If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    'Data toevoegen aan tabel & BSO tabel
    Dim dbsCurrent As Database, dbsBSOlogging As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb
    Set dbsBSOlogging = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("BSOlogging.accdb")
    Set rs = dbsCurrent.OpenRecordset("logging")

    dbsBSOlogging.Execute "INSERT INTO loggingBSO(stdid, stdname, gender, phone, address) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & _
        Me.cboGender & "','" & Me.txtPhone & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "')"

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO logging(stdid, stdname, gender, phone, address) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & _
        Me.cboGender & "','" & Me.txtPhone & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "')"
    Else

    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("logging")

   'update statement for current DB:

   'update data in current table'

  If rs("stdid").Value = [txtID] Then

  If rs("stdname").Value <> [txtName] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("stdname").Value = [txtName]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("gender").Value <> [cboGender] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("gender").Value = [cboGender]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("phone").Value <> [txtPhone] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("phone").Value = [txtPhone]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("address").Value <> [txtAddress] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("address").Value = [txtAddress]
  rs.Update
  End If
  End If

   'update statement for operation DB:
     Set dbsBSOlogging = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("BSOlogging.accdb")
     Set rs = dbsBSOlogging.OpenRecordset("loggingBSO")

   'update data in table'

  If rs("stdid").Value = [txtID] Then

  If rs("stdname").Value <> [txtName] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("stdname").Value = [txtName]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("gender").Value <> [cboGender] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("gender").Value = [cboGender]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("phone").Value <> [txtPhone] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("phone").Value = [txtPhone]
  rs.Update
  End If

  If rs("address").Value <> [txtAddress] Then
  rs.Edit
  rs("address").Value = [txtAddress]
  rs.Update
  End If
  End If


    End If

    'Clear form
    cmdClear_Click

    'Data refresh in list on form
    frmStudentSub.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtID = ""
    Me.txtName = ""
    Me.txtAddress = ""
    Me.txtPhone = ""
    Me.cboGender = ""

    'focus op ID text box
    Me.txtID.SetFocus
    'Set button Edit to enable
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'Change caption of button Add
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'Clear tag on txtID for reset new
    Me.txtID.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'Check if there exists data in list
    If Not (Me.frmStudentSub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmStudentSub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    'Get data to textbox control
    With Me.frmStudentSub.Form.Recordset
        Me.txtID = .Fields("stdid")
        Me.txtName = .Fields("stdname")
        Me.cboGender = .Fields("gender")
        Me.txtAddress = .Fields("address")
        Me.txtPhone = .Fields("phone")
        'Store id in Tag of txtID in case id is modified.
        Me.txtID.Tag = .Fields("stdid")
        'change caption button Add to Update.
        Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
        'Disable button edit
        Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try to limit this question to one problem, and try to make it more minimal? What isn't working, why isn't it working (error, does nothing while it should do something, or something else?), and what do we need to know about it?

Comment: Hi, the attached screenshot shows best what I try to make. I need for example 3 new Acces Databases A, B and C. Each database should contain 1 table for logging. Respecitvely, logging records should have ID A1,A2, A3, ... for database A.

Comment: You already made that clear in your question. My problem is: you have an excessive amount of code, including things like code behind close buttons, on your question. Remove all the irrelevant data, and show a clear attempt at doing what you just explained. Also, tell us what does and doesn't work for your attempt. Read in on how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Hi, the attached screenshot shows best what I try to make. Database X is the main database with 1 table. Database A, B or C also have each 1 table for the same, seperate logging. When I click cmd.Add, in Database A, the values from the form fields should be stored on the database A table named "logging" with ID = A1 but also on the Database X table named "logging" with ID = A1. (Same should be possible for Database B and C). When clicking "Edit" and "update"in Database X or Database A, B or C, the correct Record A1, B1, C1, ... should be updated in both databases in which it is present.

Comment: If it's still not clear I will try to create a simplified example and come back on this. Thanks for replying to my problem.

Comment: It's not that it's unclear what you want, but it is unclear what you've tried, and what's (not) working. Also, you should always minimize your questions, so other users can understand it more easily and it has more value for the future.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new, more simple example. Kind regards.